# "Specified value has invalid Control characters" when fetching value of a key from appSettings

Tags: c#

I am trying to sent an http post request. I am getting error "Specified value has invalid Control characters" when trying to fetch value of a key from appSettings which has to be used as a header.
Kindly help.

```
string value = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key]);
    client.Headers.Add("content-type", "application/json");
    client.Headers.Add("key", value );
```

Comment: Point 1: `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key]` this is already a string so no need to convert i believe. Point 2: What is the value in the key?

Comment: 5QRUZqMde0ecCQ0B.0

Comment: I see no problem with that. I get no errors on trying that value. There must be a control character somewhere like ' etc. You can try one thing though. Loop through all characters in `value` and for each char (say `c`) check if `char.IsControl(c)`.

Comment: I tried iterating through the string and found no control letter as well :(

Comment: So stumbled across this question while in search for some answers, as most people do. Don't know if this still troubling people, but I know of a character that throws this exception, but it is not consider a 'control character' by char.IsControl. It is the 'zero width space' and its unicode value is 8203. Maybe that is the problem here